# Where can I get ArcView 1.0?

Tags: installation, windows-7

The version is correct 1.0. Not 10.0, 1.0.  Will it run on Windows 7?

Comment: Can I ask why you would want version 1.0?  I'm just interested.

Comment: It will not run on Windows 7 at all. Dave Smith was able to get it working in a Win 3.1 VM but it was not easy.

Comment: On Windows it only runs on Win 3.1 and 3.11.  It won't even run on Windows 95.  There were also some UNIX OSs it would run on.   I ditto Bill above that the only way to get it to run on Windows 7 is inside a Win 3.1x VM, which then of course it's not really "running" on Win7, right?   The other issue here is look carefully at why you'd want to run ArcView 1.0.  If I remember correctly it could only view old PC/ArcInfo and version 5 and 6 ARC/INFO coverages.  Not shapefiles.  And not coverages created at version 7 or later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the *The Surveying, Mapping & GIS* blog post [blast from the past](http://surveying-mapping-gis.blogspot.com/2009/03/blast-from-past.html). *([direct download link](ftp://download1.geocomm.com/sd2/ARCVIEW10.ZIP))*. You'll need Windows 3.1 or Windows for Workgroups, though I wouldn't be surprised if [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) or [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) would work as well (or better!).

Comment: Plus if I remember correctly, the only spatial datasets it would read are ArcInfo 5 or 6x coverages, PC ArcInfo 3x coverages.  AV1 was pre-shapefile and certainly no geodatabases, no DBMS connect, and I don't believe any raster formats, maybe old GRID but no promises.

Answer (score 2):

arcexplorer can be used for free. But no other arcview can. It is not supported any longer and you will have a tough time finding it. Then you will have a tough time running it the last os it was supported on was win 95.

Comment: AV 3.x runs *beautifully* on Win 7 64 bits.  So maybe there's hope for ArcExplorer?

Comment: Agreed Bill.  Almost any app that was originally written to run on Win 3.1 with 32MB of RAM and a 486-66 processor is going to fly on today's machines.

Comment: not the same question but leads in the direction of a working installation for successfull migration.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/install-arcview-3-2-and-extensions-from-original-disks

Answer (score 2):

AV3.2 runs in WINE 1.0.1: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22816 -- I can't verify this.

AV3.1 seems to run in WINE 1.2.2, Ubuntu 10.4.  On my system there seems to be a problem with character I/O and fonts - many text fields are garbled.  But otherwise generally seems to work.

You might also consider ArcExplorer Java Edition for Education (AEJEE, pronounced "edgy"):  http://edcommunity.esri.com/software/aejee.   This is a Java bundle which runs on Mac as well as Windows;  and I did get it to work on a Linux system once.  AEJEE supports network mapservers (ESRI ArcIMS only unfortunately) and has a "Catalog" function which makes it somewhat more like ArcGIS with training wheels -- but if you're really interested in ArcView on Linux you should probably try WINE again.