# Install ArcView 3.2 and extensions from original disks

Tags: arcview-3

I see someone mentioned copying the c:\esri folder and pasting in/on Windows 7 64 bit. Sounds easy enough; however, I thought the installation process partly consisted of putting certain files in certain places in order for the whole thing to work? Oddly enough, I work as a GIS Specialist and know little about the computer. My oversight, excuse me.

So, I have to be led by the nose (really good and thorough intructions).

Could I really just copy my ESRI folder on my xp machine to an external drive and then transfer it to my new machine?

Otherwise, can I use my original installation disks?

Thanks in advance for the education

John

Comment: I have copied simple .exe files between different computers successfully. The question usually isn't if you can copy the program. The question is if the licensing will allow it to run. It is definitely worth a try.

Comment: also see [Install ArcView3 on 64bit Windows?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/install-arcview3-on-64bit-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:

On Windows XP machine, copy **AV_GIS30** folder from **C:\ESRI\AV_GIS30** and paste to Windows 7 machine **C:\ESRI** for **C:\ESRI\AV_GIS30**

On Windows XP machine, copy **ESRI** folder from **C:\Program Files\Common Files\ESRI** and paste into Windows 7 machine **C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files** for **C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ESRI**. This is where the *mtch.dll* needs to be.