# OGR/GDAL threading results in low core utilization

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, parallel-processing

I'm trying to process some raster data using ogr/gdal and I can't seem to get full utilization of all the cores on my machine.  When I only run the process on a single core, I get 100% utilization of that core.  When I try to split into multicore (in the example below, by chunking the x offsets and putting them in a queue), I get pathetic utilization on each of my 8 cores.  It seems like it only adds up to 100% utilization across each core (e.g. 12.5% on each).

I was concerned that using the same datasource was the bottleneck, but I then I duplicated the underlying raster file for each core... and core utilization is still crap.  This leads me to believe that ogr or gdal is somehow behaving like a bottleneck shared resource but I can't find anything online about that.  Any help would be much appreciated!

This is the "helper" function that runs inside each Worker thread:

```
def find_pixels_intersect_helper(datasource, bounds_wkt, x_min, x_max):
    bounds = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(bounds_wkt)
    rows_to_write = []
    for x_offset in range(x_min, x_max):
        for y_offset in range(datasource.RasterYSize):
            pxl_bounds_wkt = pix_to_wkt(datasource, x_offset, y_offset)
            pxl_bounds = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(pxl_bounds_wkt)
            if pxl_bounds.Intersect(bounds):
                rows_to_write.append(['%s_%s' % (x_offset, y_offset), pxl_bounds.Centroid().ExportToWkt()])
```

Comment: Unlikely, but did you check if memory is the bottleneck?

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx - yep.  Memory is definitely not the bottleneck.  Been trying to track this thing down all day... this is pretty weird.

Comment: It may be that the raster driver you are using is simply not designed to be called from more than one thread at a time. Reference: http://www.mail-archive.com/gdal-dev@lists.osgeo.org/msg07283.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK.  That was a day of my life that I'll never get back again.  Turns out the problem was not in the code I posted above.  That's totally fine.  Turns out that this was a case of threading.Thread vs. multiprocessing.Process.

As pointed out in the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html):

> The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency,
>   effectively side-stepping the Global Interpreter Lock by using
>   subprocesses instead of threads. Due to this, the multiprocessing
>   module allows the programmer to fully leverage multiple processors on
>   a given machine

Thus, threading.Thread is for IO-intensive operations, multiprocessing.Process is for CPU intensive operations.  I switched to multiprocessing.Process and everything works great.

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/basics.html) to learn how to use multiprocessing.Process

Comment: I was just going to suggest that, I wasn't sure which implementation (there are also [3rd party implementations](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing)) you were using :) I have used that recently to speed up a neat building shadows tool here: [Port “Producing Building Shadows” Avenue code to ArcGIS 10](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19935/port-producing-building-shadows-avenue-code-to-arcgis-10/20352#20352)

Comment: +1 I was about to post that you should have a word on the GDAL-dev mailing list; but I'm now pleased you didn't! This has been squirrelled away for future reference.

Comment: FWIW (probably not very much), I read somewhere people are collecting funds to try to fix the global interpreter lock (GIL) problem.  I think it will be for 3.x.