# Full utilization of CPU-cores with gdalwarp

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, parallel-processing

I need to process many large GeoTiff files with `gdalwarp`.
For this I have used the following command:

```
gdalwarp -r cubic -s_srs EPSG:25832 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -cutline shapefile.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha file1.tif file2.tif /path/to/output/out.tif
```

The problem here is that only one CPU core is used and the calculation takes a very long time. Now I've seen that `gdalwarp` has the option `-multi`.

So I tried the following command:

```
gdalwarp -multi -r cubic -s_srs EPSG:25832 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -cutline shapefile.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha file1.tif file2.tif /path/to/output/out.tif -wo NUM_THREADS=4
```

Now, `gdalwarp` uses 4 cores, but the utilization per core is only at 25%.

Is there a way to speed up the process or to fully utilize the cores used?

Comment: Just have a look at: [http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27218/ogr-gdal-threading-results-in-low-core-utilization](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27218/ogr-gdal-threading-results-in-low-core-utilization)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a Linux OS, you could consider using [`GNU parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)  to process multiple files in parallel.

For instance, a simple example using `gdalinfo` in parallel is:

```
 cat list_of_images.txt | parallel -j 4 gdalinfo {}
```

Where `list_of_images.txt`, is a text file containing the filename.

To address your above example, you will need to put your command into a script that will accept multiple arguments (e.g. input and output filenames). You could then do something like:

```
cat list_of_images.txt | parallel -n 2 -j 4 ./script.sh {}
```

Where `-n` is the number of arguments and `-j` is the number of cores you want to use. Leave out `-j` to run one job per core.

The following list provides a useful set of examples based on [`GNU parallel`](http://www.shakthimaan.com/posts/2014/11/27/gnu-parallel/news.html). An alternative to GNU parallel, is [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html), which uses a similar syntax.

Answer (score -3):

Once in a seminar at Uni Potsdam I think i was told that there is the possibility to use

-core n   or   -cores n

(not quite sure about the right spelling) where n is the number of cores gdal should use.

As I remember, it was a way faster but of course leeched every bit of ressources so you can not really use the computer while processing with every core.