# Obtaining ArcView 3.2 Spatial Analysis 1.1?

Tags: spatial-analyst, arcview-3

Is it still possible to obtain and use a copy of the Spatial Analyst 1.1 extension to ArcView 3.2 in order to finish a final project at a University?

Comment: the software is not available online free, not supported, the university should have up to date versions for students.

Comment: You need to provide more details! ArcView 3.2 has been depreciated for years and it is unlikely that you will be able to acquire it with an active license. However, if you give some information on what you need to accomplish, the group can likely provide alternative solutions (eg., QGIS is a free gis software with more raster functionality than AV 3.2 spatial analyst).

Comment: I need to create an isocrone of 90 minutes on the street network, around an airport.

Comment: I had an easy programme, called Accessmod that do it only on ArcView 3.2, but I miss Spatial Analyst 1.1 and now it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

Your most direct option to obtain this software will be by contacting your [local Esri office](http://www.esri.com/about-esri/offices) who will probably have to work through Esri's headquarters in Redlands, California.

Hopefully, there is an "Esri museum" that keeps copies of "one of everything" for future posterity.

However, I think you will be better to "bite the bullet" and look for a modern alternative solution as suggested by @JeffreyEvans.

Comment: For a slightly different take on "modern alternative solutions" see the comment thread at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/20168.